# Erorr python websocket server : unpack requires a buffer of 1 bytes

Tags: python

I am new to python, I am creating a websocket with pyhton as server and javascript as client, I got them to communicate but I cannot pass very extensive data because it throws me this error when the python function receives and tries to decode the bytes and the PAYLOAD_LENGTH.
This is my function that treats the received bytes

```
    def parse_frame(self):
        data = self.conn.recv(2)

        FIN = (data[0] >> 7) & 1
        RSV1 = (data[0] >> 6) & 1
        RSV2 = (data[0] >> 5) & 1
        RSV3 = (data[0] >> 4) & 1

        OPCODE = data[0] & 0xf
        MASK = (data[1] >> 7) & 1

        if not MASK:
           self.close_handshake(1002)
           
        #print(data[1])
        PAYLOAD_LENGTH = data[1] & 0x7f
        #print(PAYLOAD_LENGTH)
        if PAYLOAD_LENGTH == 126:
            data = self.conn.recv(2)
            
            PAYLOAD_LENGTH = struct.unpack('B', data)[0]
        elif PAYLOAD_LENGTH == 127:
            data = self.conn.recv(8)
            print(data)
            PAYLOAD_LENGTH += struct.unpack('B', data)[0]

        MASKING_KEY = self.conn.recv(4)

        PAYLOAD_DATA = self.conn.recv(PAYLOAD_LENGTH)

        PAYLOAD_DATA = self.unmask(PAYLOAD_DATA, MASKING_KEY)

        return OPCODE, PAYLOAD_DATA
```

```
Waiting connection at port 5000
1
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\digit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\digitalife\token\server\wsprotocol\server.py", line 359, in run
    self.data_transfer()
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\digitalife\token\server\wsprotocol\server.py", line 226, in data_transfer
    OPCODE, PAYLOAD_DATA = self.parse_frame()
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\digitalife\token\server\wsprotocol\server.py", line 276, in parse_frame
    PAYLOAD_LENGTH = struct.unpack('B', data)[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 1 bytes
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: I suggest using a library like `socket.io` rather than reinvent the wheel

Comment: 'B' is not the right struct code for a 2- or an 8-byte integer.

Comment: any guide where I can find the correct code? @jsonhaper